# How to read data from nested zip files in Java without using temporary files?

Tags: java, zip, zipinputstream

I am trying to to extract files out of a nested zip archive and process them in memory.

What this question is *not* about:

1. How to read a zip file in Java: NO, the question is how to read a zip file within a zip file within a zip and so on and so forth (as in nested zip files).
2. Write temporary results on disk: NO, I'm asking about doing it all in memory. I found many answers using the not-so-efficient technique of writing results temporarily to disk, but that's not what I want to do.

Example:

> Zipfile -> Zipfile1 -> Zipfile2 -> Zipfile3

Goal: extract the data found in each of the nested zip files, all in memory and using Java.

[ZipFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) is the answer, you say? NO, it is not, it works for the first iteration, that is for:

> Zipfile -> Zipfile1

But once you get to Zipfile2, and perform a:

```
ZipInputStream z = new ZipInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream( zipEntry) ) ;
```

you will get a NullPointerException.

My code:

```
public class ZipHandler {

    String findings = new String();
    ZipFile zipFile = null;

    public void init(String fileName) throws AppException{

        try {
        //read file into stream
        zipFile = new ZipFile(fileName);  
        Enumeration<?> enu = zipFile.entries();  
        exctractInfoFromZip(enu);

        zipFile.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//The idea was recursively extract entries using ZipFile
public void exctractInfoFromZip(Enumeration<?> enu) throws IOException, AppException{   

    try {
        while (enu.hasMoreElements()) { 
            ZipEntry zipEntry = (ZipEntry) enu.nextElement();

            String name = zipEntry.getName();
            long size = zipEntry.getSize();
            long compressedSize = zipEntry.getCompressedSize();

            System.out.printf("name: %-20s | size: %6d | compressed size: %6d\n", 
                    name, size, compressedSize);

            // directory ?
            if (zipEntry.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("dir found:" + name);
                findings+=", " + name; 
                continue;
            } 

            if (name.toUpperCase().endsWith(".ZIP") ||  name.toUpperCase().endsWith(".GZ")) {
                String fileType = name.substring(
                        name.lastIndexOf(".")+1, name.length());

                System.out.println("File type:" + fileType);
                System.out.println("zipEntry: " + zipEntry);

                if (fileType.equalsIgnoreCase("ZIP")) {
//ZipFile here returns a NULL pointer when you try to get the first nested zip
                    ZipInputStream z = new ZipInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry) ) ;
                    System.out.println("Opening ZIP as stream: " + name);

                    findings+=", " + name;

                    exctractInfoFromZip(zipInputStreamToEnum(z));
                } else if (fileType.equalsIgnoreCase("GZ")) {
//ZipFile here returns a NULL pointer when you try to get the first nested zip      
                    GZIPInputStream z = new GZIPInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry) ) ;
                    System.out.println("Opening ZIP as stream: " + name);

                    findings+=", " + name;

                    exctractInfoFromZip(gZipInputStreamToEnum(z));
                } else
                    throw new AppException("extension not recognized!");
            } else {
                System.out.println(name);
                findings+=", " + name;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Findings " + findings);
} 

public Enumeration<?> zipInputStreamToEnum(ZipInputStream zStream) throws IOException{

    List<ZipEntry> list = new ArrayList<ZipEntry>();    

    while (zStream.available() != 0) {
        list.add(zStream.getNextEntry());
    }

    return Collections.enumeration(list);
}
```

Comment: _"(will edit soon)"_ - Do not post partial questions.  Wait until you have the complete question formulated before posting.

Comment: Your main problem is that you first have to seek to the correct zip entry using `getNextEntry()` on the ZipInputStream.

Comment: Sorry for posting wronlgy. Will correct the post when I get from work. I am stuck with this really

Comment: In the future, please consider turning your code into a [mcve]; that is, preferably, a single .java file with a main() method that we can compile and run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Anyway, your real problem seems to be that your `zipFile` variable always refers to the outermost file. It shouldn't really be a surprise that trying to pass a ZipEntry from one of the inner ZipInputStreams into `zipFile.getInputStream()` will fail. (The only surprise is that it doesn't throw an IllegalArgumentException.) Since there doesn't seem to be any way to instantiate a ZipFile from an InputStream, it seems your best option is to abandon ZipFile and just work directly with ZipInputStreams, like JMax suggests below.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, will try to make the code better next time

Answer (score 6):

I have not tried it but using [`ZipInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) you can read any `InputStream that contains a ZIP file as data. Iterate through the entries and when you found the correct entry use the` ZipInputStream`to create another nested`ZipInputStream`.

The following code demonstrates this. Imagine we have a `readme.txt` inside `0.zip` which is again zipped in `1.zip` which is zipped in `2.zip`. Now we read some text from `readme.txt`:

```
try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("D:/2.zip")) {
    ZipInputStream firstZip = new ZipInputStream(fin);
    ZipInputStream zippedZip = new ZipInputStream(findEntry(firstZip, "1.zip"));
    ZipInputStream zippedZippedZip = new ZipInputStream(findEntry(zippedZip, "0.zip"));

    ZipInputStream zippedZippedZippedReadme = findEntry(zippedZippedZip, "readme.txt");
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(zippedZippedZippedReadme);
    char[] cbuf = new char[1024];
    int read = reader.read(cbuf);
    System.out.println(new String(cbuf, 0, read));
    .....

public static ZipInputStream findEntry(ZipInputStream in, String name) throws IOException {
    ZipEntry entry = null;
    while ((entry = in.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        if (entry.getName().equals(name)) {
            return in;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note the code is really ugly and does not close anything nor does it checks for errors. It is just a minimized version that demonstrates how it works.

Theoretically there is no limit how many ZipInputStreams you cascade into another. The data is never written into a temporary file. The decryption is only performed on-demand when you read each `InputStream`.

Comment: Jmax, i don't know the name of the files within the original input.zip file

The input zip file with nested zips contains files, a directory structure and zip files.    
E.g.  
input.zip  
Root Folder  
--file.txt  
--inputNested.zip  
  
--Nested Folder  
----file2.wht  
----inputNested2.zip    
    
and so on and so forth

Comment: Well then enumerate through the entries, check the entry name/filename and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Hi i know this answer is quite old @j

Answer (score 2):

this is the way I found to unzip file in memory:

The code is not clean AT ALL, but i understand the rules are to post something working, so i have this hopefully to help so

What I do is use a recursive method to navigate the complex ZIP file and extract 
folder
other inner zips
files
and save the results in memory to later work with them.

Main things I found I want to share with you:

1 ZipFile is useless if you have nested zip files
2 You have to use the basic Zip InputStream and Outputstream 
3 I only use recursive programming to unzip nested zips

```
package course.hernan;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class FileReader {

private static final int  BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File f = new File("DIR/inputs.zip");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(baos);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while (bis.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE) != -1) {
               bos.write(buffer);
            }

            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            bis.close();

            //This STACK has the output byte array information 
            Deque<Map<Integer, Object[]>> outputDataStack = ZipHandler1.unzip(baos);


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}    
package course.hernan;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class ZipHandler1 {

  private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

  private static final String ZIP_EXTENSION = ".zip";
  public static final Integer FOLDER = 1;
  public static final Integer ZIP = 2;
  public static final Integer FILE = 3;


  public static Deque<Map<Integer, Object[]>> unzip(ByteArrayOutputStream zippedOutputFile) {

    try {

      ZipInputStream inputStream = new ZipInputStream(
          new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
              zippedOutputFile.toByteArray())));

      ZipEntry entry;

      Deque<Map<Integer, Object[]>> result = new ArrayDeque<Map<Integer, Object[]>>();

      while ((entry = inputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {

        LinkedHashMap<Integer, Object[]> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Object[]>();
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.out.println("\tExtracting entry: " + entry);
        int count;
        byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
          BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(
              outputStream, BUFFER_SIZE);

          while ((count = inputStream.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
            out.write(data, 0, count);
          }

          out.flush();
          out.close();

          //  recursively unzip files
          if (entry.getName().toUpperCase().endsWith(ZIP_EXTENSION.toUpperCase())) {
            map.put(ZIP, new Object[] {entry.getName(), unzip(outputStream)});
            result.add(map);
            //result.addAll();
          } else { 
            map.put(FILE, new Object[] {entry.getName(), outputStream});
            result.add(map);
          }
        } else {
          map.put(FOLDER, new Object[] {entry.getName(), unzip(outputStream)});
          result.add(map);
        }
      }

      inputStream.close();

      return result;

    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to JMax.
In my case, The result of reading the pdf file is different from the expected result, It becomes bigger and  cannot be opened.
Finally I found that I had made a mistake, The buffer may not be full，
The following is the error code.

```
   while((n = zippedZippedZippedReadme.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer);
            }
```

Here is the correct code,

```
    try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("1.zip")) {
    ZipInputStream firstZip = new ZipInputStream(fin);
    ZipInputStream zippedZip = new ZipInputStream(findEntry(firstZip, "0.zip"));
    ZipInputStream zippedZippedZippedReadme = findEntry(zippedZip, "test.pdf");
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        File outputFile = new File("test.pdf");
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
            int n;
            while((n = zippedZippedZippedReadme.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0 ,n);
            }
            fos.flush();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        System.out.println("time consuming:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000.0);
    }
```

hope to be helpful!